# how can I loop through an if else statement?

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, loops

I'm trying to loop through this statement to give me a game winner but I want each game winner to be displayed ever 1000 ms. Right now it's looping through the whole thing and giving me the whole list every 1000 ms. What would be the proper way to word this so that it loops and displays each individually every 1000 ms?

```
request("https://api.sportradar.us/ncaamb-t3/games/2017/03/02/schedule.json?api_key=*************", 
    function (error, response, body) {
        if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
            var data = JSON.parse(body);
            data.games.forEach((v) => {

                var homeName = (v.home.name);
                var awayName = (v.away.name);
                var homeScore = (v.home_points);
                var awayScore = (v.away_points);

                if (homeScore > awayScore) {
                    time = setInterval(function (time) {
                        console.log('statuses/update', 
                                    { status: homeName.toUpperCase() + " WIN!" },
                                    function (error, data, response) {});
                    }, 1000);
                } else {
                    console.log('statuses/update', 
                                { status: awayName.toUpperCase() + " WIN!" },
                                function (error, data, response) {});
                }
            });
        }
    });
```

Comment: Why are you passing a callback to `console.log()`?

Comment: @mscdex just so I can see what it's doing for now.

Comment: Your question is rather vague

Answer (score 0):

For anyone interested, this is how I ended up making it work, seems to do the trick!

```
request("https://api.sportradar.us/ncaamb-t3/games/2017/03/06/schedule.json?api_key=**************", 
    function (error, response, body) {
        if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
            var data = JSON.parse(body);
            data.games.forEach((v,i) => {
               setTimeout(() => {

                var homeName = (v.home.name);
                var awayName = (v.away.name);
                var homeScore = (v.home_points);
                var awayScore = (v.away_points);

                if (homeScore > awayScore) {
                        console.log('statuses/update', 
                                    { status: homeName.toUpperCase() + " WIN!" },
                                    function (error, data, response) {});

                } else {
                    console.log('statuses/update', 
                                { status: awayName.toUpperCase() + " WIN!" },
                                function (error, data, response) {});

                }
            }, i * 1000 );
            });

        }
    });
```